# error: assigning to 'int' from incompatible type 'void'

Tags: c, string, function, void, return-type

I am trying to write a function that will take in a string and a character, and will return the index of where the character last occurs. I am having trouble compiling this, as seen by the title of the question, I get an error:

> error: assigning to 'int' from incompatible type 'void'

I have tried changing the "void" of the function to "int", and then have tried to get the function to print the result, however this resulted in a different set of errors. I am just confused, because my teacher has always shown us functions that have always had "void" as the return type, and this type of return is the only one our class has looked at so far.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void findLast (char string[], char letter){

    int Num[20];
    int i;
    int count=-1;

    for (i=0; i<strlen(string);i++){

        if (letter==string[i]){


            count=count+1;
                Num[count]=i;
        }
    }

    int result=Num[count];

}


int main (void){

    char string[20];
    char letter;
    int result;

    printf("Enter your string: ");
    scanf("%s", string );

    printf("Enter your letter: ");
    scanf(" %c", &letter);

    result = findLast(string, letter);

    printf("%d", result);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: If you intend to return a value the declared return type should be `int` rather than `void` and there should be a `return` statement in the function.

Comment: Change return type to `int`, and put `return Num[count];` at the end of your function.

Comment: If you're trying to find the last occurrence of a character in a string, then you should start at the end of the string and scan backwards. In other words `for (i = strlen(string) - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (letter == string[i]) return i;`

Answer (score 1):

Your code function has type void that means no return value. Just change the type of function as int and return it with the result.

Modified code:

```
int findLast (char string[], char letter){

    int Num[20];
    int i;
    int count=-1;

    for (i=0; i<strlen(string);i++){

        if (letter==string[i]){


            count=count+1;
                Num[count]=i;
        }
    }

    int result=Num[count];

    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @HolyBlackCat mentioned, your function needs to return the value, and should be written as follows:

```
int findLast (char string[], char letter){    

    return Num[count];    
}
```

The `void` keyword specifies that nothing will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

The type `void` indicates that the function does not return a value. Since your function is supposed to return an integer you need to replace `void` with `int` and return the result using a return statement. Also the variables *Num* and *count* are not needed. In your `for` loop the function *strlen* is called multiple times. It is more efficient to use the string terminator as the loop guard. Here is a simplified version:

```
int findLast(char string[], char letter)
{
    int result, i;

    result = -1;
    i = 0;
    while (string[i] != '\0') {
        if (string[i] == letter) {
            result = i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}
```